# Unable to install new OS

Tags: system-installation, bootable

I've been trying to dual install Windows 7 and Linux Mint (64bit) on my computer, currently running Linux Mint (32bit).
I've got the `.iso` files for both OSs, and have made bootable USBs for each, but they both seem unable to boot.
I can't recall the specific errors in each case (I'll try again and update with more details); but neither managed to progress to the point of starting an installation, and it seemed most of the time the computer wouldn't even realise a bootable medium was attached.
Edit: as per Update 3, only the Windows medium seems to be consistently malfunctioning, with what seems like a successful Linux installation in progress.

If it matters, I've managed to use both of the `.iso`s to run in VirtualBox

### Update 1: Attempted Linux Install

Below is a summary of events

1: Inserted bootable medium
2: Pressed `Del` to enter the BIOS settings
3: Reordered devices
4: Saved settings to CMOS, restart
5: Shown Linux Mint screen saying "Automatic boot in x seconds"
6: Pressed `Enter`
7: Shown screen saying "Welcome to Linux Mint " with a list of options
8: Selected "Start"
9: Kernel panic

### Update 2: Attempted Windows Install

Steps 1-4 as above
5: Regular boot into current OS

It seems the bootable medium was completely ignored

### Update 3: Reattempted Linux Install

1: Inserted bootable medium into USB3 drive instead of USB2
Steps 2-4 as above
5: Shown Linux Mint screen with nothing other than a header
6: pressed `Enter`
7: apparent kernel panic, followed by regular seeming boot
8: successfully booted from USB

Currently installing. I'm not sure if the success this time was because I used a different USB drive (I believe I tried it previously with no success) or if it was random chance.

Comment: _I can't recall the specific errors in each case..._ - ideal conditions for remote diagnosis...

Comment: I have since updated with the specific errors

Answer (score 2):

Here's several things that could have gone wrong, in order of most likely first. Before you start following these instructions, make sure you know how to get into the BIOS on your PC. If you don't, look it up with your favourite search engine. The keys that you need to press differ depending on the computer model.

Now, with that out of the way, here's the list:

(1) If you simply drag and drop or copy and paste the .iso file onto the USB drive, it's not possible to boot from it (with traditional methods). Here's a screenshot showing what NOT to do (ignore the other files and folders; I didn't have a clean USB to demonstrate with):
[image: file copied to flash drive]

Instead, you need to use a tool to write the .iso image directly to the USB drive. I recommend [UUI, the Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). It's very easy to use. If you used it correctly, you should see several files and folders on the USB drive once it's finished.

EDIT: UUI is Windows only. Since you currently run Mint, I suggest you use [Etcher.io](https://etcher.io/), but if you're feeling brave, try using dd. Some say that dd stands for "data destroyer", and it certaintly lives up to its reputation - be careful!

(2) You extracted the files contained in the .iso to the USB drive with an archive tool like 7-Zip. This won't work because certain invisible flags need to be set on the USB device for the BIOS to treat it as bootable.

You should use UUI (see above).

(3) Everything is set up correctly, but you aren't following the correct procedure to boot from the USB.

Many computers won't automatically boot from a USB just by restarting with it plugged in. As the computer restarts, look for on-screen hotkeys like "F9: Change boot device" or "F10: Enter BIOS". These vary greatly between computers. Try ESC, F1-F12, and DEL. If you get into the BIOS, change the boot order so that USB devices are at the top and restart. If you get into a boot menu, you should see the USB appear if it's plugged in. If you can't get any menus to open, search for your computer's model and "BIOS hotkeys" or similar to find out what to press as it boots.

(3) SecureBoot. Basically, PC manufacturers have stopped allowing  "unsigned" operating systems to boot. Linux distros are very often unsigned, usually because signing an image means paying the manufacturer.

You can almost certainly change the option in the BIOS named SecureBoot to allow booting Linux (and Windows versions older than 8, I believe) like normal.

(4) A 64-bit machine may not boot a 32-bit operating system willingly, because the manufacturer doesn't want you to. This can normally be changed.

Check the BIOS for appropriately named settings. Mine was called "Legacy support".

(5) Your computer may not support booting from a USB drive. Check your BIOS and see if anything like "USB Floppy" or "USB External Drive" are available in the Boot Order menu. Or, search your computer's model online to find out that way.

If it can't boot from USB, use image writing software to burn the .iso to a writable CD and boot from that.

Comment: 1-2: I used Linux Mint's USB Image Writer  
3: I have adjusted the settings in the BIOS to prefer bootable media  
3-5: Unless my BIOS was updated, this shouldn't be an issue, as I previously installed my current Linux Mint (32bit) installation from a bootable medium, and both OSs I intend to install now are 64bit

Comment: Edited my answer: I *highly* recommend using Etcher to create bootable drives on Linux. I've tried the image writer that you used and it could have gone better. Since you currently run a 32-bit OS and you want to install a 64-bit OS, make sure your processor is actually capable of running 64-bit software ;)

Comment: As explained, telling the BIOS to "prefer" bootable USBs doesn't work on one of my machines (HP 1000 series laptop). I have to enter the boot menu every time I want to use a USB.

Comment: I definitely checked that it's capable of running a 64 bit os. I remember being surprised to find out. I probably made a mistake when I initially installed Mint, thinking my machine was 32 bit due to its age.

Comment: All the dual-boot guides I've read say that it's wise to install Windows first, then Mint. Mint detects an existing Windows install and sets up the GRUB dual-boot. Windows however doesn't care about Mint and overwrites the MBR with its own bootloader, which is apparently annoying to replace with GRUB. I read your updates; good luck!

Comment: I had heard that about installing windows first, and have done that each time I've dual-installed in past; however as I can't seem to make any progress on installing windows, I figure I might as well improve my Mint install while I wait